# How to create a feedback shader in android AGSL?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, fragment-shader, android-graphics

I'm on Android 13 (tiramisu) and use the new [RuntimeShader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RuntimeShader) API to write a pixel shader in [AGSL](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/graphics/agsl/agsl-quick-reference) (Android Graphic Shader Language), in order to use it in a composable as background. So far all works.

Now I want to create a feedback effect, where the shader can eval pixel of it's previous rendered result. This requires to prepare an writable input buffer to be passed to the shader. The shader looking like this

```
@Language("AGSL")
val SHADER = """
    uniform shader feedback;
    half4 main(float2 coord) {
      return feedback.eval(coord).bgra; // simple swap
    }
""".trimIndent()
```

the buffer would be the uniform variable feedback.

First I tried to create a bitmap, to use it as a BitmapShader as proposed [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RuntimeShader#setInputBuffer(java.lang.String,%20android.graphics.BitmapShader)) and tried to use it as

```
val shader = RuntimeShader(SHADER)
val shaderBrush = ShaderBrush(shader)
shader.setInputBuffer("feedback", BitmapShader(???))
```

However, the bitmap is the wrong mechanism, since the shader requires hardware rendering (as pointed out by https://twitter.com/chethaase).

Next attempt was to create a [RenderNode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RenderNode), and draw the shader into a recording canvas, and attach the shader as a render effect.

```
myRenderNode.setRenderEffect(RenderEffect.createRuntimeShaderEffect(shader, "feedback"))
```

So far this works for static render nodes, it is elaborated more in this [article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/rendernode-for-bigger-better-blurs-ced9f108c7e2). But the moment I want to re-use the same render node, and overwrite it in the next rendering cycle, it crashes.

```
// keep a full screen copy
val feedbackCanvas = myRenderNode.beginRecording()
feedbackCanvas.drawRenderNode(myRenderNode)
myRenderNode.endRecording()
```

The crash is something lo-level, containing no information I can interpret:

> Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR) in RenderThread.

I tried also double buffering with the same result.

My question is, how to repeatedly save render result and pass it to the shader? Any hint would be great

Comment: edited to reflect some progress I had

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution, using the BitmapShader but with a bitmap which remains on the hardware. This bitmap can be created using [Picture](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Picture). To make a copy of the screen

```
val paint = Paint()
val shader = RuntimeShader(SHADER)
val shaderBrush = ShaderBrush(shader)
shaderBrush.applyTo(size, paint, 0.5f)

val picture = Picture()
val canvas = picture.beginRecording(rect.width(), rect.height())
canvas.drawRect(rect, paint.asFrameworkPaint())
picture.endRecording()

// this is a bitmap with Config.HARDWARE
hardwareBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(picture)
```

and then to pass the hardwareBitmap to the shader

```
shader.setInputBuffer("feedback",
     BitmapShader(hardwareBitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP))
```

the performance is a little underwhelming but fair enough for my case, but maybe there is still some copying of data between CPU and GPU, which could be optimized